# Loop through files in directory, and compare latest 2 files for duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, recursion

I am writing a python 2.7 script to compare the latest (2) files in a list returned from `all_current_files` this lists all of the file names in a directory e.g. `myimage.jpg, myimage1.jpg, etc.`

For example, if my list looked like:

```
1  myfile1.jpg
2  myfile2.jpg
3  myfile3.jpg
4  myfile4.jpg
5  myfile5.jpg
6  myfile6.jpg
```

defined as `list = ['myfile1.jpg','myfile2']` etc..

if the differences between the hashes of file `6`, and `5` was *10*, then the script would do nothing, if it was less than *5*, it'd delete it.

I'm having trouble formulating how to compare the last 2 elements in the list in a recursive fashion (starting from the end), until all list items are compared - can someone help?

I currently have:

```
def purgeDups():
    print "purging duplicate images every hour...\n\n"
    all_current_files = os.listdir('filllll...in...image...dir...here')
    for file in all_current_files:
        #check latest file... and compare to second latest file based on timestamp of file, recurse until no more files.

        #begin comparing files...if difference between latest all_current_files and second latest is less than 5, delete
        latest = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(<<latestfilefrom2linesabove>>))
        secLatest = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(<<secondlatestfrom2linesabove>>))
        compare = latest-secLatest
        if int(compare) < 5:  
            os.remove(<<latestfilefrom2linesabove>>)
            os.remove(<<secondlatestfilefrom2linesabove>>)
```

Thanks much.

Comment: how do you determine latest files?

Comment: Thats what im trying to figure out. How to get the last 2 items in an interative nature. For example compare 5+6, then 5+4, then 4+3, then 3+2, etc

Comment: @John Why don't you just use a nested loop, and compare all possible pairs?

Comment: unless you want to find which file is last modified from the directory, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅs method will be sufficient.

Comment: Can one of you give me an example based off @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for recursion here. If you want to compare all possible pairs, I'd recommend you use a nested loop, like this:

```
for f1 in os.listdir('.'):
    for f2 in os.listdir('.'):
        if f1 == f2 or not os.path.exists(f1) or not os.path.exists(f2):  # don't compare the same file, or files that have already been deleted
            continue 
        ... # file comparison code here
```

Comment: Thanks @Coldspeed - just wondering, how f2 on `line2` is going to compare the *second to last* file still left? Or will it just choose any available file?

Comment: `f2` iterates over all files, so if `f1` is the second to last file, and it still exists, then it will be compared.

Comment: so the line `if f1 == f2...` is saying if f1 and f2 exist, compare them and continue?

Comment: @John Not so. If `f1 == f2` means, if f1 and f2 _refer to the same file_, then I want the inner loop to _skip the current comparison_ and **continue** to the next one.

Comment: Gotcha, well i want to compare the hashes, so I would assume I'd have to add in the comparison logic after `for f2 in os.listdir('.'):` correct?

Comment: @John You'd add it exactly where I've kept the `...`.